# Is there a procedure to sample from an array according to its reversed priorities using a sum-tree?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to sample from an array according to both its priorities and its reversed priorities. By using a sum-tree structure, it is straight-forward to have prioritized-sampling. However, I could not find out how to sample reversed-prioritized.

Let's say we have an array [1,2,3,4] and I sample one element at each iteration. If I perform N iterations (and N is a very large number),I expect to get the first element N/10 times, the second element 2N/10 times etc. by using prioritized sampling. In reversed prioritized sampling setting, I expect to get the first element 12N/25 times, the second element 6N/25 times and the third element 4N/25 times, and the fourth element 3N/25 times. I could not think about an algorithm to carry out reversed-prioritized sampling.

For clarity, this article explains algorithm of prioritized sampling using sum tree: https://www.fcodelabs.com/2019/03/18/Sum-Tree-Introduction/

Comment: Could you please explain reversed-prioritized sampling with simple words in your question? I don't know where the values 12/25,6/25,4/25,3/25 in your example come from.

Comment: @Stef priority proportional to 1/p, normalized.

Comment: You're asking for python; have you tried with `random.choices` with the `weights` optional argument? `random.choices(population, weights=[1/p for p in priorities], k=N)`

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner in python:

```py
import random    # choices

population = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
priorities = [1,2,3,4]
N = 100

random.choices(population, weights=[1/p for p in priorities], k=N)
```

Or, if you want to calculate exact weights as integers rather than floats:

```py
import random    # choices
import math      # prod

population = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
priorities = [1,2,3,4]
N = 100

product = math.lcm(priorities)     # python<=3.8 doesn't have lcm, but can use either  math.prod(priorities)  or  math.prod(priorities)//math.gcd(priorities)
weights = [product // p for p in priorities]  # integers proportional to 1/p

random.choices(population, weights=weights, k=N)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I could have used "random.choices". However, my array consists of approximately 1000000 elements and "random.choices" function is very slow when compared to sum tree. That's why I want to use sum-tree

Comment: The page you linked explaining sum-trees claims that choosing one random element with weights is O(n). There is no justification for this claim and I'm pretty sure random.choices spends no more than O(log(n)) time per choice. I guess the page you linked assumes that selecting a random elements requires searching through the cumulative weights list linearly; but it can also be done with binary search; see line `[population[bisect(cum_weights, random() * total, 0, hi)] for i in _repeat(None, k)]` at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/random.py#L480 ; `bisect` is binary search.

Comment: In any case, the sum-trees implementation appears to rely simply on a list of weights; the main difference with `random.choices` is that the list of weights is converted into a binary tree with sums on the nodes, whereas `random.choices` builds a list of cumulative weights. So you can still build the list of weights using `weights = [product // p for p in priorities]`, and then pass it to your sum-tree algorithm.